# aplay doesn't recognize sound device

Tags: alsa, vmware-workstation

ubuntu15.10 on VMWareWorkstation12.

From `lspci`

```
02:02.0 Multimedia audio controller: Ensoniq ES1371 / Creative Labs CT2518/ES1373 (rev 02)
```

From `aplay -l`

```
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

From `alsa-info.sh`

```
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=4f7d951dc2c2401fedba5aae46f4e5d13e3d4e2a
```

Comment: Does `modprobe snd-ens1371` work?

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-ens1371 not found.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But It's hard to compile enc1371 driver :(

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu 15.10?